# Preserve folder structure Cocoa Pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I have create a simple and private pod with this tutorial: http://pablin.org/2013/05/18/cocoapods-for-internal-libraries/

In fact my repo has just a group of classes

All is ok and I can install my pod perfectly. The only problem is all files are installed inside of the main folder so it doesn't preserve the folder structure.

I have this folder structure, repository named: myRepository

```
 Classes 
 |
 ------ foo.h and foo.m
 ------ Controller Layer
        |
        ----------- foo2.h and foo2.m
 ------ ViewLayer
        |
        ----------- foo3.h and foo3.m
```

All files are copied inside of a folder called myRepository.

This is my podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "fooClasses"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "Common clases of foo"

  s.homepage     = "http://foo.com"

  s.license      = 'BSD'
  s.license      = { :type => 'Foo License', :file => 'LICENSE.txt' }

  s.author       = { "me" => "me@me.com" }

  s.platform     = :ios, '7.0'

  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/myRepository.git", :tag => "0.0.1" }

  s.source_files  = "**/*.{h,m}"

  s.requires_arc = true
end
```

I have tried with s.preserve_path = "*" and s.preserve_path = "Classes"

Any idea?

Thanks!!!!!!!!

Comment: Cocoapods v0.36 fixed this problem https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/2647

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well I have achieved to create  my own folders with subspec.

You can create a subspec with this line:

```
s.subspec 'folder name' do |ss|
    ss.source_files = 'files'
    ss.frameworks = 'frameworks'
end
```

The ss.frameworks is not mandatory.

You can see the complete answer from the CocoaPods mail list:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cocoapods/0kV8r2xnqA8

Thanks mcitrrus

I preferred to follow the AFNetworking pod spec:

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking.podspec

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is trying to achieve. Subspecs are intended to modularise your Pod - ie. you can have optional components. I think he just wants to maintain some kind of folder hierarchy in the Pods project. `preserve_path` doesn't appear to do this either since according to the docs `By default, CocoaPods removes all files that are not matched by any of the other file pattern.`

Comment: @itsthejb well, the one who answers is the OP :]

Comment: Personally I don't think this is what you want and shouldn't be practiced. A subspec doesn't refer to folders since iOS doesn't use name-spacing. I believe subspecs are for pods inside of a pod. Take AFNetworking as the example.

Answer (score 2):

If you work with development pods a lot then the default project structure that cocoapods creates has numerous problems:

- If you don't have at least one file at the root of your `source_files` / `resources` etc then the root directory(s) doesn't get an equivalent group in the project.
- The *location* of groups point to the root of your pod directory (and not necessarily where your source files are).  This means you cannot just right click the group and "Add Files" because it put files in the wrong location.
- The order of groups and files differs between modules because things are sorted by name and your pods obviously have different names that may or may not appear before `Frameworks` / `Pods` / `Dependencies` / `Support Files`.

---

I was looking for a solution that addresses all of the above and have finally come up with the following:

### Prerequisites

I setup my pods with a directory structure as follows (example shows pod named `SomeLib`)

```
Example/
   SomeLib-Example/...
   SomeLib-Example.xcodeproject

fix_project_structure (this is an empty text file)

SomeLib.podspec

Sources/
   FolderA/
      ClassA.swift
   FolderB/
      ClassA.swift

Tests/
   fix_project_structure (another empty text file)
   FolderA/
      ClassATests.swift
   FolderB/
      ClassBTests.swift
```

### Step 1 - Have Groups Mirror Directory Hierarchy

In your `podspec` file we utilitise the empty `fix_project_structure` that lives in the root to fix the group structure...

```
  s.source_files = 'Sources/**/*.{swift}', 'fix_project_structure'
  s.resource_bundles = {
    s.name => ['Sources/**/*.{xcassets,json,storyboard,xib,xcdatamodeld}', 'fix_project_structure']
  }

  s.test_spec 'Tests' do |test_spec|
    test_spec.source_files = 'Tests/**/*', 'Tests/fix_project_structure'
  end
```

### Step 2 - Reorder and Fix-Up Group Locations

*This is actually an optional step (see comment)*

Add the following `post_integrate` step to your `Podfile`...

```
post_integrate do |installer|

  # Fix up the Development Pods so they are easier to work with.
  # The following changes are made to any pod that contains a `fix_project_structure` file
  #  - Removes the (now redundant) `fix_project_structure` file
  #  - Moves the root {project_name} group to the top
  #  - Moves the {project_name}/Sources group to the top
  #  - Moves the {project_name}/Tests group below {project_name}/Sources
  #  - Repoints the {project_name}/Tests group so it reflects its location on disc
  # Note this script makes no functional changes to the pod so you should be able to comment out 
  #   all of this script and have things continue to work just fine
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|

    fix_files = project.files.select { |file| File.basename(file.path) == "fix_project_structure" }
    project_name = "#{File.basename(project.path, '.xcodeproj')}"
    next if fix_files.nil? || fix_files.empty? || project_name.nil?

    puts "#{project_name} -> #{project.path}"
    puts "  `fix_project_structure` file(s) FOUND"
    puts "    Removing `fix_project_structure` file(s) from project entirely"
    fix_files.each { |fix_file| fix_file.remove_from_project }

    project_group = project.groups.find.find { |group| group.to_s == project_name }
    next if project_group.nil?

    puts "  `#{project_name}` group FOUND"
    puts "    Moving `#{project_name}` group to top"
    project.main_group.children.delete(project_group)
    project.main_group.children.insert(0, project_group)

    sources_group = project_group.groups.find.find { |subgroup| subgroup.to_s == 'Sources' }
    if sources_group.nil? != true
      puts "    `#{project_name}/Sources` group FOUND"
      puts "      Moving `#{project_name}/Sources` group to top"
      project_group.children.delete(sources_group)
      project_group.children.insert(0, sources_group)

      tests_group = project_group.groups.find.find { |subgroup| subgroup.to_s == 'Tests' }
      if tests_group.nil? != true
        puts "    `#{project_name}/Test` group FOUND"

        puts "      Moving `#{project_name}/Test` group below `#{project_name}/Sources`"
        project_group.children.delete(tests_group)
        project_group.children.insert(1, tests_group)

        puts "      Adjusting `#{project_name}/Test` group and immediate children location"
        tests_group.set_path("#{tests_group.real_path}/Tests")
        tests_group.children.each do |tests_child|
          tests_child_path_before = tests_child.path
          tests_child.set_path("#{tests_child.real_path.to_s.gsub('/Tests/Tests/', '/Tests/')}")
          #puts "      '#{tests_child.path.to_s}' (previously '#{tests_child_path_before}')"
        end
      end
    end

    project.save

  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer/question is outdated due to changes made in the 0.36 version of cocoapods.

[PR 2647](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/2647) added default grouping behaviour as long as you are using a ":path" pod. As of 1.3.1 the behaviour is that it will traverse the /Classes/... structure until it sees either a file or a second subfolder and start grouping from there in the .xcodeproj file.

Comment: ":path" pod only local to the client project: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#using-the-files-from-a-folder-local-to-the-machine